# Laravel 5 skip exception hander

Tags: php, laravel-5, exception, payment-gateway

I'm integrating payment gateway to Laravel 5 project, there's a callback response from payment gateway site,

**e.g. POST http://example.com/payments/response**

However, the response is in 419 status if payment failed.

I have created a route to handle this, e.g.

```
Route::post('payments/response', [
    'as' => 'payments.response',
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@response'
]);
```

BUT, it always fall into the **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{   
    if (in_array($request->route()->getName(), ['payments.response'])) {
        // HOW TO SKIP THE EXCEPTION HANDLER ???
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I want to proceed the response to goes to my `PaymentController`, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. The error actually is `TokenMismatchException`. Thus, my solution is

edit **app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
protected $except = [ 
    'payments/response', <------- ADD THIS
];
```

Now it can proceed to the Controller

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting Call to undefined method app/Exceptions/Handler.php you need to declare controller as get not post.

Comment: the POST is by the payment gateway, I can't change it. So I can only listen a POST request by the payment gateway

Comment: I figured out. The answer below. TQ